# ajax is not completing the request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using CodeIgniter framework for this project.

Ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#set_like').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: '/noutati/articol',
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function () {
              alert('Succes!');
           }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="set_like" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url();?>noutati/articol" method="post">   
<input type="submit" name="submit-like-up" data-id="<?php echo($li_position); ?>" class="like-up" value="submit_up" /> <span class="counter-like-up<?php echo($li_position); ?>"><?php echo($comment->like_up); ?></span> 
<input type="submit" name="submit-like-down" data-id="<?php echo($li_position); ?>" class="like-down" value="submit_down" /> <span class="counter-like-down<?php echo($li_position); ?>"><?php echo($comment->like_down); ?></span>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
if($this->input->post('submit-like-down') == "submit_down") {
    $arg = $this->input->post('current_like_down') + 1; 
    $this->mu_model->updateLine('like_down', $arg, 'comments');
    $arg2 = "down";
    $this->mu_model->insertLikesRelationship($arg2);
    }
```

In php it checks which submit has been made and should complete the action. But it shows the Succes! alert, but is not completing the PHP request. Any ideas why?

Comment: `but is not completing the PHP request.` What makes you think so?

Comment: You could always use the network inspector in Chrome developer tools to see the raw response of the AJAX request to verify that the problem isn't server side with your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

In the php code can you put this statement as the first statement and tell what is the alert message after adding an alert in the js. I will edit the answer once you get me the proper reply. If I am adding as a comment the code may not be readable.

JS:

```
success: function (data) {
     alert(data);
}
```

PHP:

```
echo $this->input->post('submit-like-down');
```

Comment: I have found the mistake. I was using one function, and was checking if the input submit was clicked. Now I have different functions for each submit. Thank you!